# "value of count cannot be computed" when it depends on an AWS SSM parameter data source

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform project that I've been configuring using [AWS Systems Manager Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html). Imagine a Terraform project with the following `variables.tf`:

```
variable "stack_name" {
  type    = "string"
  default = "stack"
}

variable "vpc_cidr_block" {
  type = "string"
}

variable "subnet_config_public_subnets" {
  type = "list"
}

variable "subnet_config_private_subnets" {
  type = "list"
}
```

`terraform.tfvars` might look like this:

```
vpc_cidr_block                = "10.1.0.0/16"
subnet_config_public_subnets  = ["10.1.2.0/24", "10.1.4.0/24", "10.1.6.0/24"]
subnet_config_private_subnets = ["10.1.1.0/24", "10.1.3.0/24", "10.1.5.0/24"]
```

Instead, imagine `variables.tf` contained this instead:

```
variable "stack_name" {
  type    = "string"
  default = "stack"
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "vpc_cidr_block" {
  name = "/terraform/${var.stack_name}/vpc_cidr_block"
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "subnet_config_public_subnets" {
  name = "/terraform/${var.stack_name}/subnet_config_public_subnets"
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "subnet_config_private_subnets" {
  name = "/terraform/${var.stack_name}/subnet_config_private_subnets"
}

locals {
  vpc_cidr_block                = "${data.aws_ssm_parameter.vpc_cidr_block.value}"
  subnet_config_public_subnets  = "${split(",", data.aws_ssm_parameter.subnet_config_public_subnets.value)}"
  subnet_config_private_subnets = "${split(",", data.aws_ssm_parameter.subnet_config_private_subnets.value)}"
}
```

Now, as long as I have SSM parameters set with the correct names, I can use `${local.vpc_cidr_block}` instead of `${var.vpc_cidr_block}` everywhere in my project.

This works *perfectly* as long as I'm working with existing resources and an existing state file. That is, if I *create* my resources using the first variables/tfvars files and then change over to the SSM datasource. But if I start from scratch using the SSM version, I get a `value of 'count' cannot be computed` error from resources that depend on `${length(local.subnet_config_private_subnets)}` and `${length(local.subnet_config_public_subnets)}`.

I can't figure out why this would be happening, especially when the values don't cause any trouble running `refresh`, `plan`, or `apply` against existing resources.

Assistance and/or suggestions on how to get to the bottom of this would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: Are you managing the SSM parameters as well in Terraform? Or are you configuring these manually and then using data lookups? I've personally always used input variables for things like CIDR blocks so you don't get this chicken and egg situation. You could look at the "depends_on" flag: https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/dependencies.html - but i think that only refers to resources and might not help in your situation.

Comment: I'm not managing the SSM parameters in terraform. They're created by a different script as part of the Terraform configuration process.

Comment: try wrapping the split() function: ["${split(",", var.CSV_STRING)}"]. The documentation says that you need to wrap in some cases to make a list.